# Calender styles are not working in React js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
<div data-provide="calendar"></div>
```

When i'm using this Html attribute, the calender is loading but this calender is not having any styles. I can't understand why these styles are not applying for this calender.

I'm using this calender by "bootstrap-year-calender".

I also included css and js files provided by "bootstrap-year-calender".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css2/bootstrap-year-calendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css2/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiSo4yN97tS6CIfMqJCXItYCwgzVkIJVc&libraries=places"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Please verify and provide a solution for me.

Comment: https://github.com/jayakar723/calendar                                                                         Github link..... Those who feel like it is not correct Please check once

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet Alvin, It is just showing the UI, When i used <div data-provide="calendar"></div>            But when i'm using $("#data").calendar, I'm getting error like , .calendar is not a function, I think it is about importing jQuery into my file, I'm not getting jQuery right into HTML file

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

After seeing your github code, I think I have found your problem. You are, in fact, using Bootstrap's CDN to include Bootstrap `css` and `js` code, but **you are using Bootstrap v4 when "[the plugin requires Bootstrap v3.0.0 or later](https://github.com/Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar)"**. This is a bit mis-leading, because technically v4 is "later than v3.0.0"

Still, the **bottom line is that you should be using Bootstrap v3**.

To do this, you need to change your CDN references in your static file.

Use the following instead (taken from [Bootstrap's v3.4.1 Download Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#download):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I did this with the repository that you provided, and running on my local machine, it shows this:

[image]

Comment: Well, Thanks for reply Alvin, But it remains same. Let i explain how i created file. Then check once and answer me again.                                                                                          1. I installed  bootstrap-year-calender          2. Added js and css files min.css, min.js             3. Placed <div data-provide="calender"> </div>                                                             4. Imported those jquery and css files in Index.html

Comment: @Jayakar Yes, that would be helpful. I noticed that you tagged your question with `reactjs`, but it's not clear from your code how any of this is related to ReactJS at all. Perhaps you would like to start a [React code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that shows how you are trying to use `bootstrap-year-calendar` within ReactJS.

Comment: @Jayakar In your original post, can you edit to include the remainder of your `<head>` section from your `index.html` file? That is, include the parts where you include JQuery and Bootstrap files?

Comment: https://github.com/jayakar723/calendar   Here i provided github link @Alvin, Please check once..

Comment: @Jayakar I've updated my answer to you, based on the code you provided.